# Javascript includes behavior for non ASCII text based on browser (Mozilla Vs Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, indic

I am writing a simple app where text comes in, certain words are to be replaced and the text is sent out again. It all works well as long as I am working with ASCII characters.

I now want to do the same for Indic text. I was initially using `str.replace()` and found out that it was not replacing anything. I then checked if `str.includes()` works. It turns out that `str.includes("नमन")`  works (returns true) on Firefox but not on Chrome. I find this very strange. Can someone point out if I am missing any settings?

Comment: Assuming that `str` is loaded in a way that its contents are not corrupted (for instance, by using the wrong text encoding delivering it from the server to the client), `includes` should work identically on Chrome and Firefox. There are no settings involved, other than settings on the server (etc.) that ensure the correct text encoding is used. So my suspicion is that the text encoding is not being preserved. I'd still expect the results to be the same across browsers, but once you're letting things guess at what the encoding is, you're already in trouble. :-)

Comment: (`str` and your JavaScript code, I should have said. If you write your JavaScript code with `str.includes("नमन")` in it [where the text is literal like that], you need to be sure that however that code is stored [whether it be UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, etc.], it's delivered to the browser saying correctly what that encoding is, so that when it arrives at the browser the literal still specifies the same characters.)

Comment: I am getting the input as innerHTML of an element. Could that be playing a role?

Comment: That should be fine assuming the page and the script are loaded with the correct encoding.

Comment: Sorry for asking what might sound like a very silly question. How do I go about verifying the encoding that has been used? I am debugging using a VS Code plugin for Chrome and `str.includes("नमन")` works in the debug console of vs code but not on the browser itself. Said page works in Firefox though....

Comment: Look in the network tab of the browser when you open your page. You're looking for the `Content-Type` response header, which should say both the type (`text/html`, `text/javascript`, etc.) and the encoding `; charset=utf-8` for instance). Check the actual source files being served to ensure that they're in that encoding (VSCode shows you the encoding of the currently-open file in the lower right-hand corner of the UI). If (for example) the files are UTF-8, then you want to see `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. I strongly urge you to use a single encoding for all of your textual...

Comment: ...files (UTF-8 is a good choice for texts that are primarily in non-east-Asian languages). If the server is leaving off `charset` or specifying a different one than the content of the actual files, that's the problem. Modify the files and/or server configuration so that the server includes the `charset` and the files are in that charset. Lastly, check the HTML of the page itself, it may have a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag in the `head`. If so, ensure it matches everything else (if not, consider adding one that does). Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have added the `meta charset="UTF-8">` tag and it suddenly works. Thanks a lot! I will read up a bit more about it to see why it worked in one browser but not in another.

Comment: That's great!! :-)